# What's the difference between bnet-endpoint and p2p-listen-endpoint in v1.0.0 config.ini?

Tags: nodeos, network

Here are two parameters which are located in `config.ini` in [v1.0.0](https://github.com/eosio/eos/tree/v1.0.0)

### bnet-endpoint

```
# the endpoint upon which to listen for incoming connections (eosio::bnet_plugin)
bnet-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:4321
```

#### p2p-listen-endpoint

```
# The actual host:port used to listen for incoming p2p connections. (eosio::net_plugin)
p2p-listen-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:9876
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `net_plugin` and `bnet_plugin` are responsible of to the Peer-to-Peer network. The P2P network is the network that is between the Block Producers.

However, `net_plugin` is the old plugin for the P2P network. Whereas, the `bnet_plugin` is a newer and optional protocol plugin that works side-by-side with the existing `net_plugin`. But, a `bnet_plugin` only communicates with other plugings of the same kind.

The `p2p-listen-endpoint` is for the `net_plugin`. While, `bnet-endpoint` is for the new `bnet_plugin`.

Source:

> ### EOSIO v1.0 Release Notes (since Dawn 4.2)
>
> With the release of EOSIO v1.0 we’ve got a few small changes from Dawn
>   4.2. Below is a summary of the more interesting updates since our last release.
>
> ### Introducing bnet Plugin
>
> This release introduces an alternative P2P network protocol based upon
>   boost::beast websockets and enables multi-threaded networking and
>   faster syncing.
>
> This net plugin works side-by-side with the existing net plugin,
>   though it will only talk to other bnet_plugins on the network. It is
>   entirely independent / optional. To get up and running with the new
>   plugin, simply include eosio::bnet_plugin in your config file or
>   through the command line.

Reference: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases