# What are bnet_plugin and net_plugin?

Tags: net-plugin

Today I read fork database, I see something about net_plugin & bnet_plugin, they make me confuse. In my opinion, bnet_plugin which receives block from peer. But I cannot found this code.
Can you help me more understand this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question has been elaborated on here: [What's the difference between bnet-endpoint and p2p-listen-endpoint in v1.0.0 config.ini?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/590/whats-the-difference-between-bnet-endpoint-and-p2p-listen-endpoint-in-v1-0-0-co/1068#1068)

> Both net_plugin and bnet_plugin are responsible of to the Peer-to-Peer
>   network. The P2P network is the network that is between the Block
>   Producers.
>
> However, net_plugin is the old plugin for the P2P network. Whereas,
>   the bnet_plugin is a newer and optional protocol plugin that works
>   side-by-side with the existing net_plugin. But, a bnet_plugin only
>   communicates with other plugings of the same kind.
>
> The p2p-listen-endpoint is for the net_plugin. While, bnet-endpoint is
>   for the new bnet_plugin.

---

### bnet_plugin as described in the docs:

> bnet_plugin provides an p2p protocol to persistently synchronize two
>   blockchains using a very simple algorithm:
>
> find the last block id on our local chain that the remote peer knows
>   about if we have the next block send it to them if we don't have the
>   next block send them a the oldest unexpired transaction

Link: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bnet_plugin

---

### As for the net_plugin, you can get a better understanding of it based on the flags that can be set:

```
  --p2p-listen-endpoint arg (=0.0.0.0:9876)
                                        The actual host:port used to listen for
                                        incoming p2p connections.
  --p2p-server-address arg              An externally accessible host:port for
                                        identifying this node. Defaults to
                                        p2p-listen-endpoint.
  --p2p-peer-address arg                The public endpoint of a peer node to
                                        connect to. Use multiple
                                        p2p-peer-address options as needed to
                                        compose a network.
  --p2p-max-nodes-per-host arg (=1)     Maximum number of client nodes from any
                                        single IP address
  --agent-name arg (="EOS Test Agent")  The name supplied to identify this node
                                        amongst the peers.
  --allowed-connection arg (=any)       Can be 'any' or 'producers' or
                                        'specified' or 'none'. If 'specified',
                                        peer-key must be specified at least
                                        once. If only 'producers', peer-key is
                                        not required. 'producers' and
                                        'specified' may be combined.
  --peer-key arg                        Optional public key of peer allowed to
                                        connect.  May be used multiple times.
  --peer-private-key arg                Tuple of [PublicKey, WIF private key]
                                        (may specify multiple times)
  --max-clients arg (=25)               Maximum number of clients from which
                                        connections are accepted, use 0 for no
                                        limit
  --connection-cleanup-period arg (=30) number of seconds to wait before
                                        cleaning up dead connections
  --network-version-match arg (=0)      True to require exact match of peer
                                        network version.
  --sync-fetch-span arg (=100)          number of blocks to retrieve in a chunk
                                        from any individual peer during
                                        synchronization
  --max-implicit-request arg (=1500)    maximum sizes of transaction or block
                                        messages that are sent without first
                                        sending a notice
  --use-socket-read-watermark arg (=0)  Enable expirimental socket read
                                        watermark optimization
  --peer-log-format arg (=["${_name}" ${_ip}:${_port}])
                                        The string used to format peers when
                                        logging messages about them.  Variables
                                        are escaped with ${<variable name>}.
                                        Available Variables:
                                           _name  self-reported name

                                           _id    self-reported ID (64 hex
                                                  characters)

                                           _sid   first 8 characters of
                                                  _peer.id

                                           _ip    remote IP address of peer

                                           _port  remote port number of peer

                                           _lip   local IP address connected to
                                                  peer

                                           _lport local port number connected
                                                  to peer
```

Link: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/net_plugin

---

All of the plugins for nodeos may be found here at the bottom left: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/

Comment: Thank @Nat, but why the EOS not remove or merge them?

Comment: I'm sure they will as time goes on.  Their chief focus is elsewhere right now.

Comment: Bnet plugin has since been removed.